# Excel VBA Evaluate method with dynamic parameters

Tags: excel, vba, parameters, evaluate

I have a worksheet with values in A,B,C,D columns. First 3 are entered by user and the column D is generated using a macro like below,

```
Dim Dvalue(1 To 100) As Long

For rownum = 1 To 100
    If my_condition_1 Then
        Dvalue(rownum) = my_value_1
    ElseIf my_condition_2 Then
        Dvalue(rownum) = my_value_2
    ElseIf MySheet.Evaluate(user_condition_1) Then
        Dvalue(rownum) = user_value_1
    ElseIf MySheet.Evaluate(user_condition_2) Then
        Dvalue(rownum) = user_value_2
    End If
Next rownum
```

Basically, when it fails to populate using internal hard coded conditions, it evaluates some user conditions (to true/false) and fills accordingly. There is another worksheet where the user can enter his custom conditions as text. It would look something like

```
If(A1 + B1 = C1, True, False)
If(B1 > C1, True, False)
```

As you can see, I need to evaluate it only against certain rows. The problem I am facing is how to change the row number in the user condition. User can modify any condition any time.

One option I thought about is to use a place holder (A? + B? = C?) and substitute with the row number (or tokenize on ? and stitch back). The condition must refer to same row's values only, ie all the ? will be replaced with current rownum. However performance will suffer as this replacement/stitching happens for each row.

Another option is to probably use a fixed row somewhere else, whose values will be modified during each iteration of above for loop. The user condition will always be referring to this row. This method can also be modified to use some named parameters/memory location that can be shared by vba and the formula, if possible. Yet another thought is about "active" row the condition will refer to, which will be changed during iteration. I am fairly new to vba. Hence not very sure about all these options and syntaxes.

May be this is all over-engineering. However I am more curious about the possibilities in this direction than actually being worried about having to change my approach altogether. Appreciate your help in finding a solution or even pointing out options that I can explore. I would prefer limiting the user actions to only entering the conditions and values.

Comment: since you have decided to let excel evaluate conditions anyway, there is no reason for using vba, it would be better to let the users have a playground, and learn `IF(condition, do on condition true, do on condition false)`

Comment: Perhaps write the Evaluate portion as a Function, call it from within the loop, and pass the rownum as an argument?

Comment: @Henrik, the whole workbook was like a minefield with formula in almost every cell. Performance was pathetic. 99% that was converted to macro, at the user's request itself, with a single button to refresh. This is the only place I felt the requirement was kind of dynamic (permissible value set for D). There again, part of the logic (and data set) should be enforced within the code (hence the my_condition_x part).

Comment: @barryleajo, the user conditions are dynamic. Hence implementing that logic is not possible. However I was wondering whether a callback function kind of facility is available in excel for "formula -> vba", where I can supply it with the current row's data.

Comment: In that case, I would have another worksheet, with the user_conditions on ColA and Values in ColB and ColC, the conditions in ColAwould simply be expressed as (A+B)==C using VBA style conditions, and the dangerous "Eval" method

Comment: @Henrik, not sure whether I got it completely. What I understand is that the ColB, ColC etc would contain the actual input values from current row, and needs to be updated each time in the loop before calling the Eval. Please correct me if I am wrong. I have never used this Eval either. Basically I do not get the link between the condition and current row.

Comment: nevermind, let's discuss it in the answer, where I use EVALUATE to run an excel like syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I suggest you take a look at EVALUATE()

here is a quick working example:

```
Sub SO()
     Dim Text As String
     Dim rowNumber As Integer
     rowNumber = 1
     Text = "=" & Replace(CStr(Range("C" & CStr(rowNumber)).value), "¤", rowNumber)
     Text = Evaluate(Text)
     d = Dvalue(rowNumber, Text)
End Sub

Function Dvalue(rownumber As Integer, value As String)
    Range("D" & CStr(rownumber)) = value
End Function
```

basicly it runs an excel formula, when you want it to, instead of on updates.
this helps on performance, and allows users to srite expressions like normally.. (except without the '=')

Comment: (1) I assume "C1" is the condition cell in other sheet (not data sheet). Can you give an example for a condition text here? How do I change the row number hard coded in that condition (say 9 in A9 + B9 = A9 - C9) ? (2) Evaluate(text) is not assigned to anything? (3) Regarding "d = Dvalue()", this function is not returning anything. (In my example Dvalue is actually a buffer to be written into sheet in one shot. I have edited the question to include that) (4) On running this, column D is just getting filled with the condition text, with "=" prefixed.

Comment: for an example purpose, then c1 is a cell in a worksheet.
you will need to modify that selector.

Comment: you don't..
you do what you suggested. and use a wildcard like A¤ +B¤=C¤ and then replace ¤ with another character http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php

Comment: (3) ok, I had no idea, but decided this was an option. You don't need to return anything, but some vba engine versions complain if the *returned* result is not in a variable, hence the dummy variable d

Comment: usage:
A1: number
B1: another number
C1: condition
D1: answer

Comment: It is that replacement of row number that I am more concerned about. It has to happen per row and will affect performance. I wish there was a parameterized evaluate() or a way to invoke a callback function from the formula.

Comment: true, but it is a one-off, how critical is that performance, of how huge is that datasheet?
if the performance penalty is so high as you say, excel is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: There can be up to 20k to 50k rows, and 10 to 20 user conditions. It takes about 5 to 20 seconds (I implemented split on ? and join with rownum approach). D is a status column. I can hard code the whole thing, but should be ready to change the code when they add/modify a status value (not very frequent though). Macro is doing many other things, and refreshes the whole workbook on the click itself (without any noticeable delay). It was more of a question of offering flexibility without compromising the experience. Given the background, and nature of the data, I have a bias towards the latter.

Comment: Why not just add DoEvent in the for loop? - then it may take 25 seconds instead of 20, but excel remains responsive, as events are handled.
you could even start by deleting all the old output values, that way the user may see how far the macro has come in evaluating the stuff..

Comment: Thanks. I will consider that.